# Redirect :80 to :8080/ui on Apache

Tags: apache, httpd

I need to redirect port :80 to :8080/ui. I know iptables lets you redirect :80 to :8080 but it doesn't accept the URL part, only the port. How should I do it?

It is acceptable to change the URL to :8080/ui (URL changing is OK). I can't use Tomcat AJP because I use websockets which is not supported.

Apache proxying doesn't work with websockets so it is not an option.`enter code here`

Comment: Just to be sure: you want the browser to keep the :80 URL, right? (So some forwarding/proxying invisible to the user.) And are you sure *"It is acceptable"* is not missing the word "not"?

Comment: @Arjan Its ok if the url changes, I'm not missing the "not" word. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Okay... Now that you're fine with exposing Tomcat to the internet directly: did you consider just running it on port 80 then (or use iptables for that part, if you're on Unix and don't want to run Tomcat with root privileges), and deploy the "ui" context to the root? Or use Apache's proxying, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649241/reverse-proxy-with-websocket-mod-proxy-wstunnel

Comment: @Arjan I didn't even realize I could run tomcat on :80 :D Thanks for the tip. Apache proxying doesn't work with websockets so it is not an option. I will run it on :80 I think.

Comment: Did you read the Stack Overflow link in my previous comment? Web sockets should work nicely with proxying, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is running a web server on port 80 (to send the redirect) acceptable? If not, it won’t work anyway.

I’ll go with Apache, since you already mention it in the tags. In your `httpd.conf` (or include file in `sites` or whatever), add the following line either to the top level configuration or the appropriate virtual host:

```
Redirect permanent / http://1.2.3.4:8080/ui
```

This requires `mod_alias` to be installed and enabled, which it likely is by default anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of achieving this is using a webpage on the server to redirect to your desired webpage as well (use this in combination with your iptables firewall rule change).

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection

Comment: This is only a last-resort solution because everything else is simply better.